# How to always run some code when a promise is fulfilled in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, deferred, finally

In my Angular.js application, I'm running some asynchronous operation. Before it starts I cover the application with a modal div, then once the operation is complete, I need to remove the div, whether the operation was successful or not.

Currently I have this:

```js
LoadingOverlay.start(); 
Auth.initialize().then(function() {
    LoadingOverlay.stop();
}, function() {
    LoadingOverlay.stop(); // Code needs to be duplicated here
})
```

It works well, however I would prefer to have something cleaner like this pseudo-code:

```js
LoadingOverlay.start(); 
Auth.initialize().finally(function() { // *pseudo-code* - some function that is always executed on both failure and success.
    LoadingOverlay.stop();
})
```

I assume it's quite a common problem, so I was thinking it could be done but cannot find anything in the doc. Any idea if it can be done?

Comment: If you can chain one `then()`, then you can surely chain another ... `.initialize().then(...).then(...)`. There's no "finally" as such; the final handler is the last one specified.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, that won't work because if `initialize()` fails, you still need to declare both a "success" function and a "fail" function and duplicate code in there.

Comment: Won't work, or just inelegant?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, I mean it really won't work. I have updated my example to clarify what I mean. As you can see in example 1, the code needs to be duplicated, which is not just inelegant but also harder to maintain. In example 2 (pseudo-code), the function will be executed no matter what, which avoids duplicate code. Here just chaining `then()` functions won't help since I'd still need to handle both failure and success (even though I don't care if it succeeded or not). Perhaps what I'm trying to do cannot currently be done though.

Comment: Laurent, what you want isn't currently available in Angular's lightweight $q service, which provides promises with just one method, `.then()` - see "The Promise API" [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q). The only freedom is to have one `.then()` or to chain multiple `.then()`s. You are not the first to wish for a more extensive promise API - the feature you want is formally requested [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1828).

Comment: Feature request https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2761

Comment: @OZ_, I should have mentioned it but I actually ended up implementing the feature in this pull request - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2424 It's been accepted and I guess should be part of the main Angular.js release soon.

Comment: Thank you, @Laurent. It's implemented in 1.1.5 which is on google CDN today :) I think it will not be worse if $http will have same functional "out of the box" :) At this moment I'm trying to figure out and learn how can I wrap $http with $q to get flow, described in your question.

Comment: @OZ_, I didn't check but I would assume `$http` makes use of the built-in promise service, doesn't it?

Comment: @Laurent, I thought built-in promise and $q - different things. But if not.. Will check right now.

Comment: Apparently `always(callback)` is not implemented or rolled back in angular 1.2.6. We have to use `finally` now. I wonder why the reserved word `finally` is better than `always`.

Comment: @Aleyna, interesting, when I've implemented the feature, the consensus was to use `always` since that's what jQuery is using and because `finally` is a reserved JS keyword. Eventually, it seems they went for `finally` anyway with the caveat `Because 'finally' is a reserved word in JavaScript and reserved keywords are not supported as property names by ES3, you'll need to invoke the method like 'promise['finally'](callback)' to make your code IE8 compatible`. Why not, but it seems a bit more trouble than needed.

Comment: And actually Android Browser will also throw an error if using `finally` without quotes.

Comment: @Laurent, I have checked out the discussion on your pull request. I would second `always` as well. Perhaps maintainers wished to stick with Q's original api.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

The feature has been implemented in [this pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2424) and is now part of AngularJS. It was initially called "always" and then later renamed to `finally`, so the code should be as follow:

```
LoadingOverlay.start(); 
Auth.initialize().then(function() {
    // Success handler
}, function() {
    // Error handler
}).finally(function() {
    // Always execute this on both error and success
});
```

Note that since `finally` is a reserved keyword, it might be necessary to make it a string so that it doesn't break on certain browsers (such as IE and Android Browser):

```
$http.get('/foo')['finally'](doSomething);
```

Comment: For anyone finding this from a web search, the link in the answer referred to the function `always` but it was changed to `finally` as you can see in this commit (or in the source): https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/f078762d48d0d5d9796dcdf2cb0241198677582c

Comment: @this.lau_ does the finally() have to be the last call in the chain, or can I chain more then()s off of it?

Comment: @Brian `finally` returns a promise just like the rest, so you can chain it.  However (at least on some versions of Angular) the convenience overloads `success` and `error` are only added to the immediate return of `$http`, so if you _start_ with `finally` you'll lose those methods.

Comment: @drzaus, for the record, `success` and `error` were deprecated. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 7):

I'm using Umbraco version 7.3.5 back end with AngularJS version 1.1.5 and found this thread. When I implemented the approved answer I got the error:

> xxx(...).then(...).finally is not a function

What did work however was `always`. If anyone else using an old version of AngularJS finds this thread and can't use `finally` use this code instead

```
LoadingOverlay.start(); 
Auth.initialize().then(function() {
    // Success handler
}, function() {
    // Error handler
}).always(function() {
    // Always execute this on both error and success
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For those not using angularJS, and if you're ok with catching the error (not sure if .finally() would do that), you could use .catch().then() to avoid the duplicated code.

```
Promise.resolve()
  .catch(() => {})
  .then(() => console.log('finally'));
```

The catch() might end up being useful anyway for logging or other cleanup.
https://jsfiddle.net/pointzerotwo/k4rb41a7/

Answer (score 1):

I would use ngView to render the content of the page and trigger the removal of you modal on the event $viewContentLoaded. See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngView for that event and http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope for the $on event listener.