# Javascript: When promise is fulfilled, then invoke same function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

**Note: Not a duplicate question of [How to always run some code when a promise is fulfilled in Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040263/how-to-always-run-some-code-when-a-promise-is-fulfilled-in-angular-js)** as that is specific to AngularJS.

I'm looking for something like jQuery's [done](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) or AngularJS's [finally](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

I have a promise that gets resolved or rejected. Whether it was resolved or rejected I'd like to run same function when fulfilled, as this:

```
var myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('Success!');
    if( something ) {
        resolve('ok');
    } else {
        reject('not ok');
    }
});
myPromise.then(function(data) {
    var x = 1;
    var y = 2;
    console.log(data);
}, function(data) {
    var x = 1;
    var y = 2;
    console.log(data);
});
```

The above code works. The problem is I'm copying the same function twice. I know I could have a named function like this:

```
var myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { ... });
myPromise.then(doWork, doWork);
function doWork(data) {
    var x = 1;
    var y = 2;
    console.log(data);
}
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way to:

- Write the function once, instead of `myPromise.then(doWork, doWork);`, and..
- Use anonymous function instead of named function. and..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In standard ES6 promises, just use the named function twice like in your second example.  There is no `finally` in standard ES6.

The [Bluebird promise library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/finally.html) has a `.finally()` which would work well for you.

If you literally don't care if the promise is rejected, you can turn a rejection into a fulfill like this so that it always fulfills:

```
myPromise.catch(err => err).then(() => {
   // put your code here
});
```

You could also create a `.finally()` yourself:

```
if (!Promise.prototype.finally) {
    Promise.prototype.finally = function(fn) {
        return this.then(fn, fn);
    };
}

myPromise.finally(() => {
    // your code here
});
```

When using this, the returned promise (for further chaining) will take on the value from whatever your `fn` returns.  If it returns a value, the promise will take on that value.  If it returns a promise, the parent promise will follow that new promise.  If it throws, the new promise will be rejected.

There are other implementations of `.finally()` that return a promise that always tracks the original parent promise so the state is not influenced by what happens in the `.finally()` callback.  You did not ask for that extra feature here so I didn't show that slightly more complicated implementation, but you can see a proposed implementation like that [here in section 14.2](http://www.2ality.com/2014/10/es6-promises-api.html).

Comment: Great details! <3